# ¿Cómo elimino los caracteres sobrantes de una cadena de texto, para que no los almacene otra variable?(En C)

Tags: c

estoy haciendo un programa en el que tengo que almacenar los nombre y apellidos de una persona. El problema viene cuando el usuario utiliza por ejemplo un nombre muy grande y entonces se 'come' el espacio de la variable que almacenará el apellido.
Dejo el código aquí por si ayuda:

```c
fprintf (stdout, PIDE_NOM);
fgets (nombre,TAM-1, stdin);
if (strncmp(nombre,NOMB_SALIR,NCOMP)!=0)
{
    cambionombre=strchr(nombre,'\n');
    if(cambionombre!=NULL)
        *cambionombre='\0';
    else
        strncpy(nombre,nombre,TAM);

    fprintf (stdout,PIDE_APE1);    
        fgets (apel1, TAM-1, stdin);
    cambioApel1=strchr(apel1,'\n');
    if(cambioApel1!=NULL)
        *cambioApel1='\0';
    else
        strncpy(apel1Fin,apel1,20);

    fprintf (stdout,PIDE_APE2);
    fgets (apel2, TAM-1, stdin);
    cambioApel2=strchr(apel2,'\n');
    if(cambioApel2!=NULL)
        *cambioApel2='\0';
    else
        strncpy(apel2Fin,apel2,20);
```

Los `strncpy` los he puesto por si así me resuelve el problema, pero no es el caso.
Cuando imprimo apel1Fin me sale el sobrante de lo almacenado en nombre.

Comment: Puedes mostrar un poco más de código? Me gustaría ver las declaraciones de las variables para tener más contexto.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Si tu programa está leyendo sobre un dato y escribiendo en otro entonces tu programa está mal, cualquier escritura de datos fuera de control es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

Lo que necesitas no es eliminar ningún "*carácter sobrante*", necesitas no escribirlos. Para eso te aconsejo que leas datos sobre un búfer del que controles el tamaño, si este búfer se queda pequeño para tus necesidades amplíalo con `realloc`, por ejemplo:

```c
char *leer_hasta(char fin)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    int longitud = sizeof(char) * 5;
    result = realloc(result, longitud);

    for (int leido = 0; ; ++leido)
    {
        int c = getc(stdin);

        if ((c == fin) || (c == EOF))
            break;

        if (leido == (longitud - 1))
        {
            // Necesitamos mas espacio, asignamos el 150% de lo actual.
            longitud = (longitud * 15) / 10;
            result = realloc(result, longitud);
        }

        result[leido] = c;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *x = leer_hasta('\n');
    printf("%s", x);
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVE7T8MwEJ7tX3EqQnX6ohk6hSIxwFTBxAQIubaTWBgbOQ6qoP3t4eyUUDa2u@9x350t5pUQXXemrTCtVHDZBKndor6ifyCjtxGjouYeJkYp/1LzJnCWgFLbjH5R0rNeNa0JsIa7h82moETbAMbZSodWItroT@XKZMxgAitUDA6vuDFOsB6YDbasoJSUzgNLw5SWDtXLAgqYTlObUYILpCyBVKWCYPEUm6xEl8AYEuu0K@z30Hc397cZWgnZYvTrID0mrLH6WXwOeVLGFHJyzq9iAvkqgwvIl0XU/OcoQg4xsmceU@ozOgQykfAqtN5CTxcUoXjfG9eWfTgtT958h66TXxk/2XEc/@7RULLReTOawS4ipVeK7dKjHKfjtoeuu7Y6cDAcKudlLCrug7McrIPgsYuc9C4VQVu@oN8)</kbd>. Ten en cuenta que el código es sólo ilustrativo ya que no contiene control de errores ni marca el final de la cadena leída.